# Ajax can't work with wpdb

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, wordpress

I have Simple code i had Created in Ajax,PHP and Mysql this code work fine in all Conditions Except one this one is wpdb Code to insert Data to table

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
function _(id){ return document.getElementById(id); }
function submitForm(){
    _("status").innerHTML = 'please wait ...';
    var formdata = new FormData();
    formdata.append( "m", _("m").value );
    var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
    ajax.open( "POST", "<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/ajax-insert.php" );
    ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(ajax.readyState == 4 && ajax.status == 200) {
            if(ajax.responseText == "empty"){
                _("status").innerHTML = '<div class="error"><p>Please Fill all of the Fields</p></div>';
            }
            if(ajax.responseText == "Done"){
                _("status").innerHTML = '<div class="success"><p>Done</p></div>';
            }
            if(ajax.responseText == "error"){
                _("status").innerHTML = '<div class="success"><p>Problem</p></div>';
            }
        }
    }
    ajax.send( formdata );
}
</script>
<form action="" onsubmit="submitForm(); return false;">
        <div id="status"></div>
    <label>Your Message</label><br>
    <textarea cols="50" rows="10" type="text" name="m" id="m"></textarea>
        <br>
    <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Send">
</form>
```

ajax-insert.php 
i had make code to insert data with some Conditions 
this is the code

```
<?php 
    if(isset($_POST['m'])){
        $message = $_POST['m'];
        date_default_timezone_set("Africa/Cairo");
        $date = date("Y/m/d h:i:sa");
    }if(empty($message))
        echo "empty";
    elseif(!preg_match("~^[0-9a-z\-'\s\p{Arabic}]{1,60}$~iu", $message)){
        echo "error";
    }else{
        echo "Done";
        $insert = $wpdb->insert( 'chat_support', array( 'id' => '1', 'message' => $message , 'date' => $date, 'user' => $user_ID));
    }
?>
```

if i try submit the form while textarea is Empty it give me Response that it is Empty but the Problem When i Write any thing to submit in database the code after  Else dosen't work 
The response be Please wait..... and This Response Still more thime without Doing and Thing

Answer (score 0):

It is Highly advisable to use WordPress Ajax actions, you need to hookup your function to be called to wp_ajax and it would be available throughout the wp environment

Details about how to create and call ajax functions can be viewed from here https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins

Comment: Thanks i will read it but the problem that i can't understand any thing from this wordpress codex